# Unable to setup Simple Authentication on Gremlin

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

We are trying to enable a simple authentication and add user on Gremlin Server using JanusGraphSimpleAuthenticator and HttpBasicAuthenticationHandler and credentials stored in Cassandra keyspace.

Gremlin Server yaml:

```
authentication: {
   authenticator: org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.auth.JanusGraphSimpleAuthenticator,
   #authenticationHandler: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.HttpBasicAuthenticationHandler,
   authenticationHandler: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.SaslAuthenticationHandler,
   config: {
     defaultUsername: "atul",
     defaultPassword: "password123",
     credentialsDb: conf/janusgraph-credentials-server.properties
    }
 }


janusgraph-credentials-server.properties
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=cql
storage.host=127.0.0.1
storage.cql.keyspace=userslist1
```

GremlinServer is coming up properly but unable to proceed with creation of credentialsdb

But got this exception On console when creating user

```
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/janusgraph-0.5.3/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/janusgraph-0.5.3/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
plugin activated: janusgraph.imports
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.credentials
18:01:50 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
plugin activated: tinkerpop.hadoop
plugin activated: tinkerpop.spark
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session
==>Configured localhost/127.0.0.1:8182-[67de01d1-2340-4d0d-81fc-df549884cbb5]
gremlin> :remote console
==>All scripts will now be sent to Gremlin Server - [localhost/127.0.0.1:8182]-[67de01d1-2340-4d0d-81fc-df549884cbb5] - type ':remote console' to return to local mode
gremlin> graph=JanusGraphFactory.open("conf/janusgraph-credentials-server.properties")
==>standardjanusgraph[cql:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> credential=credentials(graph)
No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.credentials() is applicable for argument types: (org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph) values: [standardjanusgraph[cql:[127.0.0.1]]]
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]

Also observed following error on gremlin-server:

360359 [metrics-csv-reporter-thread-1] WARN  com.codahale.metrics.CsvReporter  - Error writing to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.op.eval
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1014)
    at com.codahale.metrics.CsvReporter.report(CsvReporter.java:241)
    at com.codahale.metrics.CsvReporter.reportTimer(CsvReporter.java:173)
    at com.codahale.metrics.CsvReporter.report(CsvReporter.java:166)
    at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter.report(ScheduledReporter.java:116)
    at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter$1.run(ScheduledReporter.java:87)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
```

Appreciate if someone help in highlighting any additional steps that may be required to enable a simple Auth, with gremlin-server 3.4.6 and cassandra.

Thanks,
Atul

Comment: Make sure to also define your Cassandra credentials as well with `storage.username` and `storage.password`.

Comment: Also, is `credential=credentials(graph)` a valid Gremlin command?  If you're trying to build a local `credential` graph, I would think you'd want to run this: `credential = graph.traversal()`.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I tried with setting the username and password in my credential server properties but am still getting same error.  Actually i think i need to use credential = credentials(graph) as i am trying to create credential graph, where i hope i would be allowed to configure users for specific graph. But still stuck with above error when starting to create credential graph.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments above, I think Aaron is correct. This syntax:

```
gremlin> credential=credentials(graph)
```

has [long been removed](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/upgrade/#_credential_dsl_changes) going back to 3.3.3. Please find the latest syntax in the reference documentation for 3.4.6 [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.6/reference/#security), but is basically as Aaron described:

```
gremlin> credentials = graph.traversal(CredentialTraversalSource.class)
==>credentialtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> credentials.user("stephen","password")
==>v[0]
gremlin> credentials.user("daniel","better-password")
==>v[3]
gremlin> credentials.user("marko","rainbow-dash")
==>v[6]
```

And even more recently, in 3.4.9, is preferred as:

```
gremlin> credentials = traversal(CredentialTraversalSource.class).withEmbedded(graph)
==>credentialtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Stephen!  I knew something didn't look quite right there.